# how to load this query to temporary table?

Tags: sql

```
select  distinct Lc.HPSkuNumber,rd.lookup_TimeFK 
from  dbo.lookup_Compatability as LC
inner join
   (select lookup_Compatability_ID,lookup_TimeFK 
    from  dbo.ResellerData  
    where ResellerID=279 and lookup_TimeFK >=76) as RD
on LC.ID=RD.lookup_Compatability_ID
order by rd.lookup_TimeFK
```

Comment: What RDBMS specifically?

Comment: Dan, based on dbo. as part of the table name, very likely SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
into #temptable
from
(
    select  distinct Lc.HPSkuNumber,rd.lookup_TimeFK 
    from  dbo.lookup_Compatability as LC
    inner join
       (select lookup_Compatability_ID,lookup_TimeFK 
        from  dbo.ResellerData  
        where ResellerID=279 and lookup_TimeFK >=76) as RD
    on LC.ID=RD.lookup_Compatability_ID
    order by rd.lookup_TimeFK
) xx
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS-SQL there are two ways to insert data into table.

1. `INSERT INTO SELECT`
2. `SELECT INTO`

I prefer number 2 because you do not need to create temp table before fact, #1 requires temp table to be predefined.

```
select  distinct Lc.HPSkuNumber,rd.lookup_TimeFK 
INTO #temp
from  dbo.lookup_Compatability as LC
inner join
   (select lookup_Compatability_ID,lookup_TimeFK 
    from  dbo.ResellerData  
    where ResellerID=279 and lookup_TimeFK >=76) as RD
on LC.ID=RD.lookup_Compatability_ID
order by rd.lookup_TimeFK
```